# How do I set up curl to permanently use a proxy?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl

How can I set up "curl" to permanently use a proxy server in the terminal?

Comment: why was this question closed? seems quite important to me...

Comment: I suspect it was considered off topic because it did not explicitly mention how cURL was being used in a programming problem (e.g. writing a script to do something interesting). It might have just as well been formulated as a sysadmin question better suited to ServerFault.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/linux-curl-command-with-proxy

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can make a alias in your ~/.bashrc file :

```
alias curl="curl -x <proxy_host>:<proxy_port>"
```

Another solution is to use (maybe the better solution) the `~/.curlrc` file (create it if it does not exist) :

```
proxy = <proxy_host>:<proxy_port>
```

Comment: Setting the proxy in ~/.curlrc has saved me many painful hours when working from within a corporate proxy. Thanks!

Comment: what about user:pass auth to that?

Comment: You could try the format username:password@proxy:port.

Comment: If anyone comes along and is trying to accomplish this with Windows / DOSKEY, I used `alias curl=curl --proxy <proxy server:port> $*`

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20 as well

Answer (score 50):

Many UNIX programs respect the `http_proxy` environment variable, curl included. The format curl accepts is `[protocol://]<host>[:port]`.

In your shell configuration:

```
export http_proxy http://proxy.server.com:3128
```

For proxying HTTP**S** requests, set `https_proxy` as well.

Curl also allows you to set this in your `.curlrc` file (`_curlrc` on Windows), which you might consider more permanent:

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:3128
```

Comment: env variable did not work for me (in Terminal on a mac).

Comment: To proxy HTTPS traffic on mac, setting the http**s**_proxy env variable in the terminal before invoking curl, worked for me. For example, `export https_proxy=https://proxy.server.com:6443`

Comment: Also note that setting HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY (uppercase) does not work, but setting http_proxy/https_proxy (lowercase) does.

Answer (score 17):

Curl will look for a .curlrc file in your home folder when it starts. You can create (or edit) this file and add this line:

```
proxy = yourproxy.com:8080
```

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 16.04. It should be accepted answer for that OS.

Comment: Can confirm it worked for Ubuntu 20 as well.

Answer (score 14):

One notice. On Windows, place your _curlrc in '%APPDATA%'  or '%USERPROFILE%\Application Data'.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me.