# performing HTTP requests with cURL (using PROXY)

Tags: linux, curl, proxy

I have this proxy address: `125.119.175.48:8909`

How can I perform a HTTP request using cURL like `curl http://www.example.com`, but specifying the proxy address of my network?

Answer (score 503, accepted):

General way:

```
export http_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:port/
```

Then you can connect through proxy from (many) application.

And, as per comment below, for https:

```
export https_proxy=https://your.proxy.server:port/
```

Comment: When you need to proxy HTTPS traffic, the environment variable is upper case: HTTPS_PROXY

Comment: From the [man pages](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)
The environment variables can be specified in lower case or upper case. The lower case version has precedence. http_proxy is an exception as it is only available in lower case.

Using an environment variable to set the proxy has the same effect as using the --proxy option.

Comment: @BipinVayalu, what do you want to check? At this way, what I describe above, the client uses the proxy "direct way", not transparently. So, the proxy gives the standard HTTP answers (including HTTP codes). If you export a wrong http_proxy environment variable (eg. bad port...), the client could't connet to that, and it gives an error message: "Warning! Couldn't connect to remote host!", or something similar - just try it :)

Comment: If you check curl source code, you will see at url.c(line 4337 in verion 7.39) they check for lowercase version and if they can't find it, check for the uppercase.

Comment: Most users sent me a correction, now I share that. If you want to use HTTPS connection through proxy, then you should do this:

export https_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:port/

Note, that there is "http" proto in URL schema, not httpS!

Comment: Please note:
https://blog.emacsos.com/use-socks5-proxy-in-curl.html .

libcurl honours ALL_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and http_proxy vars.

Comment: May be in some cases the uppercase format of the environment variable is expected, but the right form of the answer for this question is the lowercase format.

Comment: Basicaly this is right but for general the question was related to curl - so @Karl Barker ' s answer should be selected

Comment: This is not a general way, it is Linux specific

Comment: ok, so the https_proxy does not need to be accessed via https. For example: export https_proxy="http: //your.proxy.server:8080" would allow you to do curl https: //the.website.com  (remove the space between the http: and the //, and https: and the //). I also found out in the curl man page that you can use variable ALL_PROXY instead of having to use the 2 variables http_proxy and https_proxy: "Sets the proxy server to use if no  protocol-specific  proxy  is specified"

Comment: @StephaneDesmarais please see the comments above: you don't need to write the variables with uppercase, and the lowercase form has precedence (this is for your proposal for my answer). And yes, you don't need to define the schema as https - well, you can't do that, except your proxy supports the https.

Comment: @ariween yeah, I found after proposing the change 
about lowercase and uppercase as you explain, and tried to undo my change. Thanks

Comment: @StephaneDesmarais yw :).

Answer (score 805):

From `man curl`:

```
-x, --proxy <[protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]>

     Use the specified HTTP proxy. 
     If the port number is not specified, it is assumed at port 1080.
```

Comment: curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: I get above error when I run this command: curl -x, --proxy 122.72.2.200:80 http://www.mysite.com/test.php?id=1

Comment: "-x, --proxy" means that either one can be used. The command should be either "curl -x 122.72.2.200:80 http://mysite.com/test.php?id=1" or "curl --proxy 122.72.2.200:80 http://mysite.com/test.php?id=1"

Comment: The docs are correctly quoted as above, however, the user and password should be expressed differently: `-x user:password@proxyhost:port`

Comment: if you need to curl and get via proxy do `curl -x GET mysite.com --proxy yourproxy:port`

Comment: To use a SOCKS proxy just use `socks` (or version specific ones `socks4`,`socks5`,etc) as the `protocol` e.g. `curl -x socks://socks.proxy:port`

Answer (score 168):

The above solutions might not work with some curl versions I tried them for myself(curl 7.22.0). But what worked for me was:

```
curl -x http://proxy_server:proxy_port --proxy-user username:password -L http://url
```

Hope it solves the issue better!

Comment: Run into the same issue, the curl shipped by Debian Wheezy still doesn't support the env trick

Comment: Got this instead `[1] 4812`

Answer (score 109):

Beware that if you are using a SOCKS proxy, instead of a HTTP/HTTPS proxy, you will need to use the `--socks5` switch instead:

```
curl --socks5 125.119.175.48:8909 http://example.com/
```

You can also use `--socks5-hostname` instead of `--socks5` to resolve DNS on the proxy side.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but using `--socks5-hostname` did.

Comment: @MichałRybak that will work the same but resolve DNS on the proxy side. See the [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for more details.

Comment: `curl https://api.ipify.org --proxy socks5://189.100.246.182:37339` seems to work fine for me. Is the `--proxy` option in some way inferior to `--socks5` when using socks5 proxies?

Comment: @user993683 It's version-dependent. `--proxy` is probably what you want, now, but it wasn't always supported. Also note that `socks5://` and `socks5h://` perform hostname (DNS) resolution before and after connecting to the proxy, respectively.

Answer (score 62):

as an adition to airween, another good idea is to add this into your .bashrc, so you'll be able to switch from non proxied to proxied environment:

```bash
alias proxyon="export http_proxy='http://YOURPROXY:YOURPORT';export https_proxy='http://YOURPROXY:YOURPORT'"
alias proxyoff="export http_proxy='';export https_proxy=''"
```

WHERE YOURPROXY:YOURPORT is exactly that, your ip and port proxy :-).

Then, simply doing

```
proxyon
```

your system will start to use the proxy, and just the opposite with:

```
proxyoff
```

Comment: `unset http_prox` ;) !

Comment: `your system will start to use the proxy` not completely correct, you will start/stop only in current shell and subshells

Answer (score 41):

use the following

`curl -I -x 192.168.X.X:XX http://google.com`

`192.168.X.X:XX` put your proxy server ip and port.

`-v` verbose mode it will give more details including headers and response.

Comment: This should  be the answer. Not everyone wants to specify a global variable (export) for every HTTP request performed by every HTTP client on your host. This option gives more flexibility, IMHO.

Comment: This is so useful when you're trying different proxies against an url. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

I like using this in order to get the IP under which I am seen

```
curl -x http://proxy_server:proxy_port https://api.ipify.org?format=json && echo
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 27):

For `curl` you can configure proxy in your `~/.curlrc` (`_curlrc` on Windows) file by adding `proxy` value, the syntax is:

```
proxy = http://username:password@proxy-host:port
```

Comment: That's it! Configured the proxy setting some years ago in that file and wondered today, why curl doesn't work anymore now the proxy adress changed and the env vars are all set correct. Thanks for that!

Comment: On Windows, the "_curlrc" file can (must?) be placed into the "%APPDATA%" directory.

Answer (score 25):

`curl -I "https://www.google.com" -x 1.1.1.1:8080`

Comment: Consider adding explanation to your solution.

Answer (score 16):

Just summarizing all great mentioned answers:

```
curl -x http://<user>:<pass>@<proxyhost>:<port>/ -o <filename> -L <link>
```

Answer (score 10):

With a proxy with authentication I use:

```
curl -x <protocol>://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port> --proxy-anyauth <url>
```

because, I don't know why curl doesn't use/catch **http[s]_proxy** environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to export the `http[s]_proxy` shell variable if you're just setting the proxy for a one off command. e.g.

```
http_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:port curl http://www.example.com
```

That said, I'd prefer `curl -x` if I knew I was always going to use a proxy.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo curl -x http://10.1.1.50:8080/ -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
```

> This worked perfectly for me, the error comes because curl need to set
>   the proxy
>
> Remmember replace the proxy with your proxy, mine, "example" was
>   http://10.1.1.50:8080/.

Answer (score 4):

`curl -vv -ksL "https://example.com" -x "http://<proxy>:<port>"`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your workplace, you may also need to specify the `-k` or the `--insecure` option for curl in order to get past potential issues with CA certificates.

```
curl -x <myCompanyProxy>:<port> -k -O -L <link to file to download>
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
curl -x socks5://username:password@ip:port example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

For http proxy tunnels (needed for the TLS protocol), you need to specify -p  (aka --proxytunnel) instead of -x.

[curl post about proxies](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/11/26/https-proxy-with-curl/)

tl;dr the proxy tunnel uses a newer "CONNECT" keyword instead of a modified "GET"

This was needed for the node http-proxy-middleware library.

Only got a clue once I used wget which worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

In case the proxy is using automatic proxy with PAC file. We can find the actual proxy from the javascript from the PAC URL.

And if the proxy needs authentication, we can first use a normal web-browser to access the website which will promote authentication dialog.  After authentication, we can use wireshark to capture the http package sends to the proxy server, from the http package, we can get the auth token from http header: **Proxy-Authorization**

Then we can set the http_proxy environment variable and also include auth token in the http header: **Proxy-Authorization**

```bash
export http_proxy=http://proxyserver:port

curl -H "Proxy-Authorization: xxxx" http://targetURL
```