# Not able to install rvm on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install ruby on rails on ubuntu 12.04 through rvm

I did apt-get update and installed curl. Then i entered below command in the terminal

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

But after few seconds i get an error "(7) couldn't connect to host".
Any help in getting rvm installed?

Comment: Can you connect to `get.rvm.io` manually? Try `ping`ing it - while I can access it from here, your machine might not be able to reach the server. That's the only error here.

Comment: yes i'm able to ping get.rvm.io

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some HTTPS issue, try it: 
`curl -kL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

If the error persists:

1) Are you under a NAT?

2) Is there a firewall in your network, or maybe in this machine?

3) Is there some proxy configured in your browser? If so, then curl won't be able to connect with HTTP or HTTPS without passing through this proxy. Read this: [Linux curl command with proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/linux-curl-command-with-proxy)