# Is it possible to route cURL requests through a different server?

Tags: php, curl

I'm doing development on my computer using WAMPServer but there is a service I use that whitelisted my live server's (Linux, CENTOS, Apache) IP address and so I need to make certain cURL requests go through my live server instead of being made directly from my computer. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: set up a proxy server

Comment: curl supports proxy servers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/linux-curl-command-with-proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is make part of your applications configurable.  If you are calling your own web services, make those URLs configurable so that your production servers and development servers can each use separate URLs.

Another common way is to change a `hosts` file entry so that when connecting to a specific host name, you may override the network address of that host.  I don't recommend this method though, as it is easy to forget what you have overridden, and what you haven't.