# Configure jMeter Http Request to emulate this curl command

Tags: rest, curl, jmeter

I have a problem with preparing HTTP Requers in jMeter from the curl command I have:

```
curl --insecure -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" --header 
'header-param-1: aGVhZGVyLXBhcmFtLTE=' --header 'header-param-2: aGVhZGVyLXBhcmFtLTI=' 
--header 'header-param-3: aGVhZGVyLXBhcmFtLTM=' -F "file=@C:\temp\file to upload.zip" 
--form "metadata={\"jsonParam1\": \"text1\", \"jsonParam2\": 999, \"jsonParam3\": 10222, 
\"jsonParam4\":  \"2017-10-13T23:23:02.677Z\", \"jsonParam5\": \"text5\", 
\"jsonParam6\": \"3\", \"fileName\": \"file to upload.zip\", 
\"fileType\": \"application/pdf\"};type=application/json" 
"http://localhost:7001/context/rest/v1/uploadservice"
```

Basically, it is sending a file as multipart/form-data and json in the body as application/json type. The curl command is working as expected, but I couldn't make jMeter do the same.

I tried to find proper solution and ended up with a promise that manually constructing body data would help, but I had no luck with it.

I am using Cygwin for curl, since I use Windows. I also tried to use postman, but also failed to configure it.

Please help.

Comment: please show us screenshot of your Http request in jmeter

Answer (score 1):

Create an HTTP Request with Header Manager as child
[image: Test Plan]

[image]Where Header Manager is:

Where HTTP Request "**Parameters**" panel is configured like this:

[image: Http Request parameters]

And "**Files Upload**" panel in it:

[image]

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't work. I am afraid I need to do it manually through "Body Data". I am struggling with that approach now.

Answer (score 1):

Just record the request.

1. Copy `file to upload.zip` to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording" and click "Create"
3. Expand `WorkBench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
4. Run your "curl" command like:

   ```
   curl -x http://localhost:8888 --insecure -X POST -H ......
   ```
5. JMeter will capture your request and store it under `Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller`

References:

- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)
- [performing HTTP requests with cURL (using PROXY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy)