# NuGet performance test using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, nuget, multipartform-data

I need to create a performance test for Nuget repository using Jmeter tool and I need to deploy/upload .nupkg files to the repository however I have a problem with uploading. I receive error number 415 - Unsupported media type. Seems like something wrong with a Content-Type or with multipart/form-data transmission which has to be used for upload. The Jmeter has such option for POST but I have PUT in my case.

The curl below publishes properly

```
curl -XPUT http://hostname/api/nuget/nuget/ -u login:password -F "package=@/home/nugetFiles/shay-1-test.2.1.0.nupkg"
```

I have unsuccessfully tried the following - added file path in the Files Upload tab in the HTTP request sampler, added HTTP Header Manager as a child and tried the upload uing several variants with different Content-Types via **HTTP Header Manager** item.

- application/x-nupkg;
- application/octet-stream;
- multipart/form-data; boundary="6aec860d-8c85-4cea-854e-a051e77873c4";

and Content-Disposition value

- Content-Disposition: form-data; name=package; filename=package.nupkg; filename*=utf-8''package.nupkg

HTTP header manager also has **X-NuGet-ApiKey** value

I also found out that the file should be added to the request body however I do not know how to do it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just record your upload request.

1. Copy `shay-1-test.2.1.0.nupkg` to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Configure JMeter for recording. The easiest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature

   - from JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
3. Open [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and click "Start"
4. Execute your [CURL request through JMeter's proxu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy) like:

   ```
   curl -x http://localhost:8888 -XPUT http://hostname/api/nuget/nuget/ -u login:password -F "package=@/home/nugetFiles/shay-1-test.2.1.0.nupkg"
   ```
5. That should be it, the recorded request will live under `Thread Group -> Recording Controller`.

Comment: Hello, I have recorded curl request and Nuget cli client's request. I suppose the recorder skip something important. The problem in the main description is related to the already recorded scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause it the following - I'm using Jmeter 3.3, the latest released version is 4.0. According to [this bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60015) multipart/form-data transmission which is necessary for NuGet client - does not work in Jmeter for PUT method.

I have checked a stable trunk Jmeter version (apache-jmeter-r1831500.zip) has  taken from [here](https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/) and was able to deploy Nuget package.

As a workaround it's possible to create a test via **OS Process Sampler** using bash commands.

Thanks everybody for help.