# ngrok doesn't work in some particular case

Tags: python, flask, remote-desktop, ngrok

I'm tunneling with ngrok to access my localhost of remote desktop.
I successfully created my forwarding URL with ngrok but it doesn't seem it works well.

Let's say when I do this `https://*******.ngrok.io/sentiment/楽` I get what I want.

But when I do this `https://*******.ngrok.io/sentiment/楽しい` I get `bad request error` but the url actually perfectly returns output on localhost of remote desktop.

I don't know what's just different, is there any encoding problem or something? I'm so in trouble. thanks.

Comment: `/楽しい` I think this endpoint is causing the issue, format the endpoint in UTF-8