# Testcafe: Failed to find a dns-record for the resource

Tags: node.js, testing, networking, automated-tests, testcafe

I am trying to run a straightforward script as below from a Macbook.  This runs fine when I try from a personal home network but fails on corporate/office network with error "**failed to find a DNS-record for the resource**".
In Macbook, the proxy is configured at system-level, so I assume the Testcafe browser session would refer to the same.  I also tried forcing the proxy in TestCafe run parameter and that didn't work either.  I rechecked the firewall settings and the node is in the allowed list of programs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, please.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Hello Google`
    .page `https://www.google.co.in/`

test('My first test', async t => {
    console.log ("Hi Google")
})
```

I have node 12.14.0, npm 6.13.4 and testcafe 1.6.1.  I also tried with testcafe 1.7.1 and the results were the same.

Comment: Can you access the mentioned web site without TestCafe?
What happens when you run curl (`curl https://www.google.co.in -o /dev/null`) on that web site? How did you specify your proxy options for running tests?

Comment: I am able to access the site from a browser manually.  Through curl, i am getting this error: "curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.google.co.in port 443: Connection refused".  For proxy, I tried the following command: testcafe chrome logintest.js --proxy proxy.mycorp.com:port

Comment: Have you tried running `curl` with your proxy settings? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9445516

Comment: curl with proxy worked.  so, i tried giving it in testcaferc file and it worked.  for some reason, it is not working when i give it as part of the run command.  but i am good now since am able to run the tests fine.  thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by specifying proxy settings in the configuration file.

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html#proxy