# Error 'event handler' not 'handling' ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, request, econnreset

I am using the library request to post data but I constantly get the error ECONNRESET even though I have an error event handler for it. Sometimes my code does indeed handle the error, but not everytime.

I have this in a loop:

```
request.post(url, {form:{data}}).on('error',
  function(err){ 
    if(err === 'ECONNRESET'){ 
       console.log('ECONNRESET') 
    }
})
```

And, as described, I still get this error:

```
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^ Error: read ECONNRESET
```

Comment: Try logging `err.message` and `err.stack` maybe that gives you more information about the nature of the error. Also [search the web, e.g.](https://www.quora.com/What-does-%E2%80%9CError-read-ECONNRESET%E2%80%9D-mean)

Comment: @KooiInc Well, I don't think I can use err.message because the error itself isn't caught (?). But when my code catches it, I get:
"tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET"
Thanks.

Comment: I would be surprised if the `err` from the `on("error" , ...)` handler wouldn't be some kind of `Error` object.

Comment: @KooiInc Well, I mean, what else could be ? I have an ```on("error", ...)``` handler but I still get ```Unhandled 'error' event```. I have tried removing this part of the code (which is the main part of it) to see if I would still get this error, and I didn't get the error.
Thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like  `.on('error', ...);` can't catch ECONNRESET after N times so the only way to solve if (afaik now) is using `process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {})`

I hope this help other people :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all the code you have using `request` in a `try {}` clause, followed by

```
catch (error) {
  console.error (error)
}
```

From something you wrote in a comment, it seems possible something is wrong with your proxy server. Can you make the request without it? If so, try that.

You also might try using the command line program called `curl` to make a similar request. `curl --verbose` will chatter about what it does, letting you see some details about what is failing. You didn't give us enough information to allow a detailed suggestion about how to use `curl`.  This may help with the proxy settings. [performing HTTP requests with cURL (using PROXY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy)