# Curl function cannot parse proxy coming from a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl, proxy

I have a proxy txt file with the format:

```
102.129.249.120:3128
102.129.249.120:8080
101.4.136.34:8080
103.228.117.244:8080
etc
```

and I am trying to create a bash script that will do (for example):  `curl -x "$IP" google.com`.
Unfortunately, curl is giving me an unsupported proxy syntax for all the proxies.
Any ideas?
BTW, I really doubt this question has been repeated as I have tried everything else to no avail.

My script:

```
Number=$(wc -l < ProxyList.txt)



for ((i=1;i<=$Number;++i))  do
ip=$(head -n ${i} ProxyList.txt | tail -n +${i})
curl -p -x "$ip" 'webpage' -H 'user-agent' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: wpml_referer_url=referer; _icl_current_language=es; PHPSESSID=tpikve1vl4ued06i082vprqdo1' -H 'If-Modified-Since: Mon, 16 May 2016 07:27:13 GMT' -H 'If-None-Match: "3d6-532f08d9d7640-gzip"' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -m 6
done
```

A small sample of my proxy list:

```
102.129.249.120:3128
102.129.249.120:8080
101.4.136.34:8080
103.228.117.244:8080
103.253.27.108:80
104.45.188.43:3128
104.250.34.179:80
105.27.238.161:80
104.154.143.77:3128
110.243.20.2:9999
111.68.26.237:8080
106.104.151.142:58198
113.252.95.19:8197
115.231.31.130:80
118.69.50.154:80
118.69.50.154:443
119.81.189.194:80
119.81.189.194:8123
119.81.199.81:8123
119.81.199.83:8123
119.81.199.80:8123
12.139.101.100:80
12.139.101.101:80
119.81.199.85:31288
119.81.199.86:8123
119.81.199.87:8123
12.139.101.102:80
124.156.98.172:443
13.228.91.252:3128
138.197.157.32:3128
138.197.157.32:8080
138.68.240.218:8080
138.68.240.218:3128
138.68.60.8:8080
138.68.60.8:3128
```

Comment: @oguzismail Done

Comment: I'd use xargs, like `xargs -I{} curl -x {} ... <ProxyList.txt`. But if ProxyList.txt have DOS line endings, it'd fail either

Comment: Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: of how to use xargs I tried echo $ip | xargs curl url and it still didn't work. Same error.

Comment: What's the error you get? Also you're missing a semicolon right before the `do` of your `for` loop.

Comment: @tectux Sorry that was a formatting error. I had a space.                                                        Error: 'url: (5) Unsupported proxy syntax in '207.154.231.213:8080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file has carriage return characters at the end of each line.
Each line in your input file ends with `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

You can check with `od`:

```
$ head -1 ProxyList.txt | od -c
0000000   1   0   2   .   1   2   9   .   2   4   9   .   1   2   0   :
0000020   3   1   2   8  \r  \n
0000026
```

So in your script, `$ip` has in fact a value of `102.129.249.120:3128\r`.

You can remove the `\r` characters with `tr` for example:

```
while read proxy; do
  curl -p -x $proxy $webpage
done < <( tr -d '\r' < ProxyList.txt )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for ip in $(cat ProxyList.txt)
do
   curl -p -x "$ip" 'webpage' -H 'user-agent' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: wpml_referer_url=referer; _icl_current_language=es; PHPSESSID=tpikve1vl4ued06i082vprqdo1' -H 'If-Modified-Since: Mon, 16 May 2016 07:27:13 GMT' -H 'If-None-Match: "3d6-532f08d9d7640-gzip"' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -m 6
done
```

but the problem with curl might be, that should set the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` like this:

```
export http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128/
export https_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128/
```

Comment: Same error ... I'm using ubuntu 20.04 could that be the problem?

Comment: 'url: (5) Unsupported proxy syntax in '105.29.64.222:80

Comment: please give [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy) a try

Comment: first you set the proxy-environment-variables and then call `curl http://www.google.com` etc.

Comment: Yes. It only works if I input the ip without the variable (manually)

Comment: what is the output of `for ip in $(cat ProxyList.txt);do echo "-$ip-";done` ?

Comment: That works I have tried that as well it outputs the proxy list as normal!

Comment: @Oliver Gaida, I've seen the http_proxy / https_proxy environment variables work with _wget_, however to my knowledge that does not work with _curl_.

Comment: I tried that out with curl and it "works" (at least it gives me the same error ...)

Comment: Its been solved but thanks! And no I do not know it

Comment: This is the tool together with unix2dos to change the line-endings between dos and unix.

Answer (score 0):

As per the curl man page, the -x (or --proxy) switch can be prefixed with the protocol in front of the argument (if omitted, I assume that it defaults to http://):
`-x, --proxy [protocol://]host[:port]`

A simple bash script with xargs would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
webpage=${1:-http://google.com}
cat ProxyList.txt \
| xargs -n1 -I{} curl -p -x http://{} "$webpage" -H 'user-agent' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: wpml_referer_url=referer; _icl_current_language=es; PHPSESSID=tpikve1vl4ued06i082vprqdo1' -H 'If-Modified-Since: Mon, 16 May 2016 07:27:13 GMT' -H 'If-None-Match: "3d6-532f08d9d7640-gzip"' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -m 6
```

Comment: Still doesn't???  Same error. What version of ubuntu do you have? Or do you have another distro?? I really don't know.

Comment: 'url: (5) Unsupported proxy syntax in 'http://46.35.184.187:61003

Comment: Debian 5.4.19 / curl 7.68.0

Comment: I'm getting "curl: (56) Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT" from your proxies. That seems to be related to your "-p" switch (tunneling). Seems that the proxies don't support that? On the other hand, it shows that the "-x" part of the statements work.