# Can I make curl use a proxy without changing its command line arguments?

Tags: bash, curl

I am using this line of code:

`code=$(curl -ks -o /dev/null -i -w 'Status: ''%{http_code} -X GET www.goog.com`

but I want to change the curl to use proxy **127.0.0.1:8080** but without changing the above code.
I want to use a variable that will change it on the go.

`code=$(curl -x 127.0.0.1:8080 -ks -o /dev/null -i -w 'Status: ''%{http_code} -X GET www.goog.com`

Comment: What is the problem with doing so?

Comment: Your quotes are unbalanced; the given code won't parse.

Comment: Anyhow -- the documentation for curl describes environment variables it honors. Have you reviewed it?

Comment: Beyond that, it's simply not clear what you're asking for. Do you want a shell function that'll wrap curl to add the proxy arguments? Do you want to configure curl to use a proxy without needing any extra arguments at all? Do you want to use a parameter expansion to optional add the `-x` argument if and only if there actually is a proxy configured? Lots of options, and which one to choose is in your court, not ours.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9447493/14122 describes the environment variable approach; if that's what you want the question is a duplicate.