# JMeter gives me bad request once I run the thread

Tags: jmeter

it seems to be jmeter doesn't see the parameter required even I wrote them. I tried a lot of versions and still the samee. It works fine using postman (curl)

Comment: curl -X POST -H "app-version: 10.5.4" -H "version-name: 10.5.4" -H "version-code: 249" -H "installation-id: b12b289f-64ed-4b49-b041-9c937b6fad67" -H "ad-id: b12b289f-64ed-4b49-b041-9c937b6fad67" -H "device-type: android" -H "app-lang: en" --data $'{"country_code":"+2","countryNameCode":"EG","email":"amr@amr.com","fbCountryCode":"20","fbPhoneNumber":"1023494000","name":"amr","password":"123456","phone_number":"01023494000","type":"no_account","update_data_screen_status":0}' https://api-sandbox.core.koinz.app/api/customer/sign-up

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's not JMeter who "gives" you bad request, it's the system under test tells you that request is malformed via [HTTP Status Code 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

There is only one version which will "work" but we cannot tell you which one unless you're willing to share the "working" request details from curl and/or postman.

If you can run the request successfully using curl or Postman you can:

1. [Create a test plan from Curl command](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/curl.html)
2. Record curl command execution via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) by [running your curl request via JMeter's proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy):

   ```
   curl -k -x http://localhost:8888 your-request-parameters http://your-server-endpoint
   ```
3. [Record Postman request execution via JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

Comment: thank you, issue solved by point number 3