# JMeter(5.5) API testing fails to make a normal HTTP request, receives 502 status code

Tags: http, nginx, jmeter

I've an application hosted on nginx , I'm not able to hit that API using JMeter.
Receives below error on JMeter **Sampler Result**

```
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2022-07-21 18:39:47 IST
Load time:31316
Connect Time:4
Latency:31316
Size in bytes:151
Sent bytes:118
Headers size in bytes:151
Body size in bytes:0
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):
Response code:502
Response message:Could not relay message upstream




HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

**Response** ::

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Could not relay message upstream
Date: Fri, 22 Jul 2022 03:42:26 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Via: HTTP/1.1 m_proxy_sin
```

But this API works fine from same Host machine over **curl**, **Postman** etc.

When hit via JMeter there are no error information available in the **nginx** log as well regarding the same.

Ping to the host is works fine, the host is reachable from the test Machine.

System Details::

```
OS : Windows 10
   
C:\Desktop>java --version
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 11.0.15+10-adhoc..jdk11u)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 11.0.15+10-adhoc..jdk11u, mixed mode)

JMeter - 5.5
```

```
2022-07-25 16:25:47,348 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2022-07-25 16:25:47,351 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2022-07-25 16:25:47,354 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2022-07-25 16:25:47,354 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2022-07-25 16:25:47,354 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2022-07-25 16:25:47,354 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2022-07-25 16:25:47,354 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2022-07-25 16:25:47,354 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2022-07-25 16:25:47,369 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2022-07-25 16:26:18,057 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2022-07-25 16:26:18,057 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2022-07-25 16:26:18,057 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2022-07-25 16:26:18,057 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Comment: Is it happens only in JMeter 5.5 or also with previous versions?

Comment: Yes, its happening for previous versions as well (JMeter 5.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting this variable the issue got resolved

set JVM_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

Answer (score 0):

If this API works fine for curl or Postman just record the request from curl or Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), it will generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) in order to send exactly the same request.

- [performing HTTP requests with cURL (using PROXY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy)
- [Postman - Configuring proxy settings](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

Comment: When its redirected via JMeter Proxy, its not working, normal requests are going through


```curl -x "http://localhost:8181" "http://16.8.11.157/health"``` - **Not working**



```curl "http://16.8.11.157/health"``` - **Works**