# Testign Curl API load testing with Jmeter

Tags: api, testing, curl, jmeter, load

How should I test this in jemeter? When I import curl from tool, data not displayed in jemeter.

curl --location --request POST 'https://bruh.uselotus.io/api/track/' \

--header 'X-API-KEY: 6tZu1NaQ.PicT21tPHTHfLrYzoLzbSk2vHhvXt7Hc' \

--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \

--data-raw '{

```
"batch": [

    {

        "customer_id": "d21b769b-b824-48ad-98f1-99a4ce93eac0",

        "event_name": "task_run3",

        "idempotency_id": "07f92995-8b8f-41ad-afdc-406993b31b75",

        "properties": {

            "run_count": 4000

        },

        "time_created": "2023-03-17T01:16:41.408Z"

    }

]
```

}'

I import this curl from the tool menu of jmeter, but I am not able to see any provided data in jmeter, how can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting everything into a single line, you're using some characters which are specific to [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) and JMeter doesn't recognize them

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://bruh.uselotus.io/api/track/' --header 'X-API-KEY: 6tZu1NaQ.PicT21tPHTHfLrYzoLzbSk2vHhvXt7Hc' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"batch":[{"customer_id":"d21b769b-b824-48ad-98f1-99a4ce93eac0","event_name":"task_run3","idempotency_id":"07f92995-8b8f-41ad-afdc-406993b31b75","properties":{"run_count":4000},"time_created":"2023-03-17T01:16:41.408Z"}]}'
```

---

Alternatively you can use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733979-Recording-a-user-session-with-the-proxy) for recording the request, just start JMeter's proxy and [make cURL aware of this proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy) via `-x` command-line argument.

```
curl -k -x http://localhost:8888 --location --request POST 'https://bruh.uselotus.io/api/track/' --header 'X-API-KEY: 6tZu1NaQ.PicT21tPHTHfLrYzoLzbSk2vHhvXt7Hc' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"batch":[{"customer_id":"d21b769b-b824-48ad-98f1-99a4ce93eac0","event_name":"task_run3","idempotency_id":"07f92995-8b8f-41ad-afdc-406993b31b75","properties":{"run_count":4000},"time_created":"2023-03-17T01:16:41.408Z"}]}'
```

Comment: Thanks, It works a little, when when I run it, it displayed a fail, so Now I put only the data section in a body part in jmeter, and now its works perfectly. Thanks for helping :)