# How to send body data and file upload in single request?

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing

How to put this curl in jmeter request?

```
curl -X POST    "http://pnv6s2218.net.plm.eds.com/polarion/rest/v1/projects/Popokatepetl_Project_40/workitems/pfhmi-development2-1553/attachments" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiOiJlZDM4MDhiNy05MjdhNTBjNC01NzJkMzg5My02YTdhMDMwYSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyX0RWTFBSX1ZPTFVORFJfMjAwMSIsImlkIjoiMGZmNWJkOTAtOTI3YTUwNzUtMzVmNGJiMDgtMmViZGIzOGYiLCJleHAiOjE3NjQ4NzMwMDAsImlhdCI6MTY3MTAxMDA0MX0.jEP2wNlZ_jgAuPYnAD1ZitL0qd_JcJ54wo6VYKWPg32rD2VqF6RMNjz74q902MuuWTYgIMi3Q3w15d-T1bxo7kBRq7URRULL2MmddqwLxKQx23OfrxChZeehqCG-3IqAR_bKyvy9lmzNB4G-qPPhedEnmGi0Dy2DKfxN22ff8SK63rdxOezcC29s3qQOlBoUvu9UiNlDekXmabg_ZPFJLPGwTa6npH27f99r8ATQwUKum-6ba5OV-WexgTeg1vdblGo50A0FidqKgrCINCNttJW5MF9hp0tRUcy48FilqrmA6cYtZuPaLYwzQv8D9fe1xuNJzGZXz50Xi1eGuT5RHg" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "resource={
      "data": [
        {
          "type": "workitem_attachments",
         
          "attributes": {
            "fileName": "File Name",
            "title": "Title"
          }
        }
      ]
    }" -F "files=@Colourbom1.PNG;type=image/png"
```

There are 2 body data's, one is body data and another one is file upload date.

How can I put that in single jmeter request?

Answer (score 1):

Put what you call "body data" under "Parameters" tab:

[image]

and the file under "Files Upload" tab:

[image]

Also be aware that you can:

- Record your cURL command execution using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) by [running cURL command via JMeter's proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy). Just make sure to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. See [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing) article for more details
- It's possible to create a JMeter test plan from cURL command:

  [image]

Comment: I Have added as you suggested and executed,Its send requests like this