# Jmeter - Incorrect Response due to query parameters encoding

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

In Jmeter I created a simple GET request having query params as below

https://xxxx.com/salsvc/api/Compensation?employeeId=TestEmp1

But in listener response I get **No Item found**

Whereas if I run the same request through POSTMAN , it gives me the correct expected result

"data": [
{
"frequency": "Single",
"ItemName": "Basic Salary",
"employeeId": "TestEmp1",
"ItemId": 1
}
]

Even if I create request by importing CURL from POSTMAN , I get incorrect result.

I tried using JMETER function like encoding/decoding but no success .

I think something is incorrect with the way my query params are being treated in Jmeter . Any help will be much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying your parameters in URL query string directly:

[image]

In general if your request works in cURL or Postman you can:

- In case of cURL there is an option to create a request from the command:

  [image]
- Both cURL and Postman requests can be converted into JMeter by simply record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). You can configure cURL to use JMeter as the proxy via [`-x` command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy).

  Postman also [supports upstream proxies](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/installation/proxy/), in case of HTTPS you will need to import JMeter's certificate into Postman first

  [image]

See [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/convert-postman-api-tests) article for more details if needed.