# Luarock fails to install new pacakages?

Tags: git, curl, proxy, lua, torch

I'm running the torch7 on a ubuntu 14.04 LTS pc behind a proxy.
I have already made environment variables Http_proxy and proxy.

The default options for `wget` and `curl` and `git` has been set to run via this proxy. here are the steps I used to change the settings of the packages of [Wget proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211705/setting-proxy-in-wget), [Curl proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559103/how-to-setup-curl-to-permanently-use-a-proxy) & [git proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

The env variables are available in my `.bashrc` and `/etc/enviornment`files.

I have also added the proxy in the config.lua file as per [this](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/LuaRocks-through-a-proxy) post as well.

The error I get when i try to install this is

```
$sudo luarocks install cunn
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed loading manifest: 
Failed fetching manifest for http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks 
- Error fetching file: Failed downloading 
http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/manifest


Error: No results matching query were found.
```

Comment: Try `sudo -E luarock ....` command.

Comment: Tried it and get the same error @hjpotter92

Comment: what is the output of `env | grep -i proxy`?

Comment: Same values for root and user. 
`http_proxy=http://hpc-squid.fe.hhi.de:8080

ftp_proxy=http://hpc-squid.fe.hhi.de:8080

HTTPS_PROXY=http://hpc-squid.fe.hhi.de:8080

https_proxy=http://hpc-squid.fe.hhi.de:8080

HTTP_PROXY=http://hpc-squid.fe.hhi.de:8080`

Comment: I don't see `use_proxy=yes` variable.

Comment: But I thought that value should be set in the `config.lua` file.

Comment: no, in `.wgetrc` or better yet, in emvironment

Comment: I seems dont have a `.wgetrc` file but a `/etc/wgetrc` where there is a `use_proxy = on` variable @hjpotter92