# AWS EC2 instances in same VPC: HTTP request fails through http_proxy but not with --noproxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I have two AWS EC2 instances that were provided to me. They have only private IP addresses and they are inside the same VPC.

On instance A (10.xx.xx.76) I have Kibana running on port 5601.
On instance B (10.xx.xx.84) I am trying to make the request `curl -iv http://10.xx.xx.76:5601/api/status` but this returns:

```
...
Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'http:/10.xx.xx.82:8080'
Trying 10.xx.xx.82...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to 10.xx.xx.82 (10.xx.xx.82) port 8080 (#0)
GET http://10.xx.xx.76:5601/api/status HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.xx.xx.76:5601
User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 10.xx.xx.82 left intact.
curl(52) Empty reply from server
```

But, when I run the same command with the `--noproxy` flag, as in `curl -iv --noproxy http://10.xx.xx.76:5601/api/status`, I get the expected response from Kibana running on instance A.

More information:

- From instance B I can `telnet 10.xx.xx.76 5601`.
- Both instances share a Security Group with inbound and outbound rule with type "All traffic", protocol "all", and port range "all".
- I have updated nftables to accept port 8080, 443, 5601.

Is someone able to explain me why this may be happening?
I am not sure what is this http_proxy or how can I make this request through it.

Comment: In your instance B, curl is configured to use http_proxy (probably using one of the ways described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559103/how-do-i-set-up-curl-to-permanently-use-a-proxy)

Comment: @DusanBajic Thank you for your response. Yes, that's true. But do you know if this is expected or correct? Or do you know how I can make the http_proxy be able to communicate with instance A?

Comment: If you don't have access to instance C (10.xx.xx.82), all you can do is make sure that instance A accepts traffic from instance C (so open both OS firewall and AWS security group)